# How to insert a META HtmlElement to an existing HEAD HtmlElement for a WinForms WebBrowser?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I am trying to add a META element under the HEAD element on a web page loaded in the Windows Forms WebBrowser control.  I am doing this inside the DocumentCompleted event and when I set a breakpoint it is added to the HEAD element correctly. Howeverwhen I look in the web page source from the control it doesn't show it.

Here is a code snippet from my DocumentCompleted event:

```
Forms.WebBrowser browser = sender as Forms.WebBrowser;
if (browser == null) return;
Forms.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = browser.Document;
if (htmlDocument == null) return;

Forms.HtmlElement ie8MetaElement = htmlDocument.CreateElement("META");
ie8MetaElement.SetAttribute("content", "IE=8");
ie8MetaElement.SetAttribute("http-equiv", "x-ua-compatible");
Forms.HtmlElement headElement = htmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0];
headElement.Children[0].InsertAdjacentElement(Forms.HtmlElementInsertionOrientation.BeforeBegin, ie8MetaElement);
```

Do I need to do something else after Inserting the META element into the HEAD element? I have done similar changes to the Style property on an HtmlElement and it has worked find in this event, so not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: view source loads the original stream, if you want to get the modified html, get the outer html attribute for the document element.

Comment: I need to see it in the browser and to make sure its getting used live. Right now it isn't working as you can see in the example I am trying to add the hint for the page to use IE8 compatibility mode which will work as I can force the page into this mode when I use the full IE browser and the page works. But without being in compatibility mode the page will not render correctly. So either my changes are working but the WebBrowser control ignores the hint, or the changes are not being picked up. I need to force particular pages into compatibility mode and I can't use the registry.

Comment: You can't change the compatibility mode after the document is rendered. Of course, you can navigate again if the web site is under your control and you can add X-UA-Compatible to the web site on request. Otherwise you have to get deeper in the stack, for example use a programmable proxy to add the header and use the proxy in the webbrowser control.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to do that, but that would work for sure. Thanks for the help.